# remove/clear Lightning styling of aura:unescapedHtml

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using the tag **aura:unescapedHtml** in an aura component to render dynamically HTML code, it works great; however, it inherits the lighting styling, this overrides the styling of my code in **aura:unescapedHtml**. Is there any way to prevent **aura:unescapedHtml** to inherent the lighting styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can 'un-inherit' the SLDS-styles. However, in aura it is possible to override the CSS-attributes in the component's css file

**Bad practice alert**:
You might want to consider using the !important css keyword to override certain attributes.
(this is really not a good practice though).